# Convert Time variable to milliseconds

Tags: java

I am having a variable which is called from_time and I am reading the infor from the DB.

```
Time from_time = rs.getTime("nfrm_time");
```

How to convert the from_time into milliseconds and seconds?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the method getTime():

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Time t = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());
        long l = t.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to do the opposite if i want from milliseconds to time

Comment: *"how to do the opposite"* Did you try RTFM for the class in question?  Or are you expecting us to look it up for you and spoon-feed the information?

Comment: `and how to do the opposite` - isn't that already given in the original answer? First statement is millis to time, second one is time to millis.

Answer (score 5):

`java.sql.Time` extends `java.util.Date`, and has `getTime()` method which returns millis.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the millis as indicated by Bozho, you can use java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit to rather easily convert to seconds (and hours, days, etc).

Even though it's actually in the concurrent package, I found this to be of great use for general cases.